# How to find the min of a column in every nth intervals of a file, using sed, sort, tail?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to find the minimum of the 5th column of a file in every 12th interval of that and save the associated line into a new file.

To find the minimum of the last 12th line I can use

```
tail -n 12  $FILEname | sort -g -k 5,5 | head -1|  awk '{print}'> tmp.out
```

But how can I perform such a process iteratively?
I have tried

```
while read $FILEname
do
 ....
done
```

which was not successful.

The file looks like

```
4.7 0.17    0.529   0   4.4846
4.7 0.17    0.529   1   4.5437474
4.7 0.17    0.529   2   5.63229739
4.7 0.17    0.529   3   4.672385157
4.7 0.17    0.529   4   4.698922468
4.7 0.17    0.529   5   4.699977195
4.7 0.17    0.529   6   4.699969329
4.7 0.17    0.529   7   3.69999717
4.7 0.17    0.529   8   4.6999998
4.7 0.17    0.529   9   2.7
4.7 0.17    0.59    10  3.9999998
4.7 0.17    0.59    11  4.69999999998
5   1   0.59    0   4.49569846
5   1   0.59    1   4.54330574
5   1   0.59    2   4.63739653
5   1   0.59    3   3.67233957
5   1   0.59    4   4.6989202468
5   1   0.59    5   4.699912595
5   1   0.59    6   4.6999329
5   1   0.59    7   4.69999999717
5   1   0.59    8   4.69999998
5   1   0.59    9   3.2547
5   1   0.529   10  4.69999999998
5   1   0.529   11  4.69999999998
```

with almost 2000 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
awk 'NR%12 == 1 { min=$5 ; line=$0; } 
    { if ($5 < min) { min=$5 ;line=$0; } } 
    NR%12 == 0 { print line ;} 
    END { if (NR%12) print line ;} '
```

this basically reset min every 12 lines (1,13,25, ...), compute min, and print it for line 12,24,36,...

END statement print last min if number of line is not a multiple of 12.

note that you can one line this statement, call it with

```
awk '....' input_file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This precisely gave me the minimum. To have the line, I have slightly modify the script to "awk 'NR%12 == 1 { min=$5; line=$0 } { if ($5 < min ) {min=$5; line= $0} ; }  NR%12 == 0 { print line ;}  END { if (NR%12) print line ;} '  tmp.out > tmp2.out "

Comment: @Shasa I fixed it in my answer.